# update_user_meta add value on the top on existing value

Tags: plugins, users, user-meta, options, multi-author

I'm working on a plugin that will allow people to favorite authors on WP site.

When you click on Favorite this author button, it will send author ID to below function and save that value in DB.

Below is the code I save value to `FAV_AUTHORS_META_KEY` in `wp_usermeta` table.

```
$user_id = fav_authors_get_user_id();
$fav_author_id = 2;
update_user_meta( $user_id, FAV_AUTHORS_META_KEY, $fav_author_id );
```

If I have author ID `2`, it will save that on DB. However, when I send different author ID, `update_user_meta` will override existing value instead of adding the new value.

How do I make it keep the existing value and add new value on the top of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no built-in functionality to append meta values you'll need to do it manually. If you plan on adding multiple values I would suggest saving it as an array but it will serialize it in the database which will make it harder to run [WP_Meta_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query) on.

```
$user_id        = fav_authors_get_user_id();
$fav_author_id  = 2;
$author_list    = get_user_meta( $user_id, FAV_AUTHORS_META_KEY, true );

if( empty( $author_list ) ) {   // There was no meta_value, set an array.
    update_user_meta( $user_id, FAV_AUTHORS_META_KEY, array( $fav_author_id ) );
} else {
    $author_arr = ( is_array( $author_list ) ) ? $author_list : array( $author_list );  // Added in case current value is not an array already.
    $author_arr[] = $fav_author_id;
    update_user_meta( $user_id, FAV_AUTHORS_META_KEY, $author_arr );
}
```

I'm assuming what you have in place currently is not an array so I add an inline-conditional inside the else statement to convert any single values to an array. **Note** that you must pass `true` to `get_user_meta()` so that it unserializes our array.

Comment: Can you please help me out with `Delete` too? I believe I'm having the same issue... http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/211468/delete-user-meta-delete-one-value-out-of-array

Comment: @Ohsik Since is an arry you need to use PHP array_search and remove that value. That's more PHP specific than WordPress.